# DRUPAL 7 - Save user selection of exposed items per page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I set the pager to full pager then I click the link to the right titled 'Paged, X items', I scroll down, check "Expose items per page", and then  I set the different paging quantities

But when visitors visit another page (i.e. away from the current view) and come back, the exposed filter settings are remembered (e.g. the taxonomy term the user selected) but the items per page are reset to the default, not whatever the user selected on the last visit. Should that be remembered?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible at this point. See this issue and consider contributing a patch if you would like to see this functionality. https://www.drupal.org/node/1392244

Comment: Hopefully that helps! I'm sorry that it's not really a solution for you.

Comment: Don't worry, I 'll work on this subject but it's real that I just start with Drupal so I hope it is not too hard to implement.

Comment: @InsRg: Drupal has quite an API that can be difficult to master, but I believe is also very rewarding.

Comment: If anyone have the same problem please check this link : https://www.drupal.org/node/1482424 they have the solution